# Get the first value in a dictionary from a list of keys that occurs pythonically

Tags: python

I have a list of items that may or may not be keys in a dictionary. There is an order to the items. So I want to go from the first to the last and search for them in the dictionary. The first one to appear in the dictionary is the one that I want the value of. If none are in there, I want None.

I want this in a clean pythonic one liner, since it should be simple. I thought about something like this (but the syntax does not work):

```
value = dictionary.get(key) for key in list_of_keys while value == None
```

or maybe with if else like

```
value = dictionary.get(key) if key in dictionary or list_of_keys == [] else key = list_of_keys.pop()
```

but the second one only works if I initialize the key.

anyone got a simpler way to do this?

Comment: The pythonic way would be to loop over the potential keys until you find the first one with a corresponding value, probably using a try-except

Comment: So you think that pythonically this wouldn’t be a one liner...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
value = next((dictionary[key] for key in list_of_keys if key in dictionary), None)
```

**Explanation:**

`(dictionary[key] for key in list_of_keys if key in dictionary)` will create a python generator.

By using `next`, it will stop iterating through the python generator when the first valid key is found. If the generator is empty, it will return the second argument as the default value, in this case, `None`.

Comment: This one does exactly what I’m looking for. Nothing more, nothing less. But won’t you get a key error if you do it that way instead of with dictionary.get?

Comment: In this case, Python will only run `dictionary[key]` if `key in dictionary`, so no need to use `dictionary.get`, but you can use it if you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
value = [dictionary.get(key) for key in list_of_keys if key in dictionary][0]
```

This will work so long as there is as the dictionary contains at least one key in list_of_keys. It makes a list of the value of each key in list_of_keys and then [0] only outputs the first one.

Testing:

```
dictionary=dict(tom=9, bob=8, rose=4)
list_of_keys=['harry', 'sam', 'bob']
value = [dictionary.get(key) for key in list_of_keys if key in dictionary][0]
print(value)
8
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution with linear time complexity would be -

```
d = dict()
# define your dict here

for k in list_of_keys:
    val = d.get(k, None) # you could also use try-except
    if val:
        print(val)
        break
```